# Finding the Value of "t" Based on a Given Distance and Equation

Tags: geometry, parametric

The question is the following:

> The position of a starship is given by the equation of $P_t = (18 + 3t, 24 + 4t, 110-5t)$. For what values of $t$ is the starship within 100 units of a space station placed at the origin?

I do not know where to start for this problem, so any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
(18+3t)^2+(24+4t)^2+(110-5t)^2=100^2
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thank you so much for your response! I got two solutions for t: 6, 10.

Comment: $50t^2-800t+3000=0$ giving the $t$ values that you state. $ \ddot \smile$

Comment: Thanks again. Just a totally unrelated question to what we have been discussing: what LaTeX code did you use for the smiley face? I have trying to get it to work, but it's to no avail.

Comment: $ \$ \text{\ddot \smile} \$ $ ... also highlight the smiley face, right click, take the show maths as ... LaTeX commands (2nd option)

Comment: Wow! I never knew that that option existed! Does that only work on StackExchange, or can I also use this whenever there is anything that is written with LaTeX commands? $\ddot \smile$

Comment: The natural statement of the problem is as an inequality, not an equality: there are many more solutions than $t=6$ and $t=10$.